# Installing app on live with availibility to modify

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, live-usb

I'm planning to use a live Linux like a (windows to go) thing
I'd searched but didn't find any solutions. so let me explain what is in my mind to help me:

I'm planning to have portable Os for my works(such as university), the shape in my mind is using a live Linux like "windows to go" and install everything you want, you unplug and plug it in another system , boom you have your data and no need such special hardware.

you may ask:
why don't you just install it on your flash drive?
because i think without live,i wouldn't have this option to be able use all hardware's and also having safe graphic option too(if it is possible & no need live, than guide me pls),

- so in short :
  how can i install apps on linux(like gimp, blender, anaconda, python and etc) in a way i could use them like live iso and also being able to not lost any changes that i make

more detail you may need:

- it's not important what distro i would work with until it works.
- my drive actually is a 32gb ram(windows to go was fine with it for test) & read write speed is about max to 20mb & it's better than my old usb2 drive.
- i'm a beginner and a noob so sorry about it
- it's not important if it is installed on flash or live booted, until it does the job
- i'm spending time on different places and can't carry laptop so it's a better option for me

thank you guys for your patient <3

Comment: You can't; a live session does not provide a write-able base system.  You need to make your personal installer and that is a hell of a lot of work that you will need to repeat for every new release you want. ",i wouldn't have this option to be able use all hardware's" ehm that is not an issue: you can install software the same way you normally do. You won't be using 3rd party drivers also in regards to hardware... unless all systems have the same brand graphics and nic you would be using generic drivers. and those get loaded by the kernel based on the hardware.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I'm not sure what specs systems would have, but if graphical apps and updates wouldn't require anything related to hardware, by that can i install Linux and my appss then boot up that usb anywhere without any bootloader?(of course i know it's not possible and need something to done, what are those something ), and again thanks for your guide

Comment: ASUS usually work well with Ubuntu.

Comment: You've provided no actual specific product on which to do it (you mention largely `linux` where this isn't a Linux site; SE *Unix & Linux* covers that), but I'd likely just use `mkusb` for most on-topic products used on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- An easy method is to use [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) to make a **persistent live** system in your USB drive. You can install application programs and save data files in such a system.
- Another method (more complicated but still quite straightforward) is to **extract and clone from a compressed image of Ubuntu Server**, and when logged into it install a desktop environment, for example Ubuntu Desktop or the light-weight Lubuntu Desktop. See the following link,

  [Ubuntu Server amd64 compressed image (when extracted) boots in UEFI and BIOS mode](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474692) .

  This will be an installed system with all the features available.

  If you select this method, I would recommend the 'Jammy' image from

  http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/jammy/daily-preinstalled/current/

Comment: Thanks for your help, i did a fast reading both links and they're promising and interesting, I'll try both of them to see witch one can work better. as a final question, any of these two solutions need anything to do to make it able to boot? For example in old and new systems can i boot on in only by choosing drive? Or somehow i need to find bootloader file manually in bios and boot it from there?(if there is note in link's,than sorry, i didn't read whole process and planing to work on it on weekend)

Comment: @Jafar, both methods make systems that can boot both in UEFI mode and BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode). -- Linux systems are usually very portable between PC computers, but there are limits. Some graphics chips and wifi chips need a proprietary driver from the chip manufacturer, and with such a driver there can be problems in computers with other hardware. If you tell us about your computer (brand name of the computer itself, of the graphics chip/card and wifi chip/card) we can give more specific advice.

Comment: It may be complicated to make wifi work in Ubuntu Server, so I would recommend a wired connection (ethernet) until you have installed a desktop environment and rebooted. (This is a smaller problem with a persistent live system, except when the computer needs a proprietary wifi driver).

Comment: Thanks, the thing is, I want to do this to have freedom and that's the thing (btw i guess i won't need any drivers for modem cuz i can use my phone as usb hot spot). Like in university there's bunch of different PC's and some of them are new and some old(don't know their specs) i want to remove this limitation and be able to have and work on my own stuff without caring to what hardware I'm using, but for finding more details im currently using i7 12700h, 16gb ddr5, 1t ssd drive, (for more details search for tuf fx507zr laptop specs)

Comment: And if it's so, i guess everything would be fine (if i don't mess up). thanks for your help and precious time 

Comment: Good luck, and share your experience (both if you fail and if you succeed) :-)

Comment: Tysm, Of course, i would like to share it for future fellows who are curious like me, but till checking and making sure on university takes some time xD

Comment: The nvidia graphics card may cause problems in the ASUS computer. Probably you must turn off the nvidia card to preserve portability or else **boot with the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset`** and in the installed system install a proprietary nvidia driver.

Comment: It would be easier if you create and test the USB boot drive in a computer without nvidia graphics (or with an nvidia chip that is a few years old) and without broadcom wifi.

Comment: Hello again! I did tested mkusb on latest Ubuntu and it works! I didn't tried to do heavy stuff or else, but for a fast try did some changes and it didn't changed successfully, but it's so slow so now I'm planning to try it on Manjaro then going to try your second solution, thanks again for your help 

Comment: @Jafar, Please notice that mkusb cannot make a persistent live drive with Manjaro, because it has a different boot structure from Ubuntu. You may find another tool or way to make that work. Anyway, I think making an *installed system in a USB drive* is a good alternative, good luck :-)